# Binding C++ methods and variables to a table, side by side

Tags: c++, c, lua

I've been attempting to create a "host" application that exposes a C++ API to Lua code, and have been fairly successful so far, but have run into snags when attempting to bind "variables" in with the methods.

The pattern I have developed to bind "classes" to lua involves each class having a `_new` and `_gc` function, as well as a static `luaL_Reg RegData[]` for each class.  I can then assign the desired functions into the RegData array, and call a helper method to bind them to lua.  The following is some code illustrating my method:

```c
int Host::_new(lua_State * ls)
{
    Host ** udata = (Host **)lua_newuserdata(ls, sizeof(Host *);
    *udata = new Host();

    luaL_getmetatable(ls, "luaL_Host);
    lua_setmetatable(ls, -2);

    return 1;
}

int Host::_gc(lua_State * ls)
{
    Host * host = *(Host **)luaL_checkudata(ls, 1, "luaL_Host");
    delete host;
    return 0;
}

const luaL_Reg Host::RegistrationData[] =
{
    { "new"  , Host::_new },
    { "__gc" , Host::_gc  },
    { 0      , 0          }
};
```

And elsewhere:

```c
void LuaState::registerObject(const char * name, const luaL_Reg data[])
{
    int len = strlen(name) + 6;
    char * luaLname = new char[len];
    snprintf(luaLname, len, "luaL_%s", name);

    // create the metatable with the proper functions
    luaL_newmetatable(_state, luaLname);
    luaL_setfuncs(_state, data, 0);

    // copy the metatable on the stack
    lua_pushvalue(_state, -1);
    // assign the index to the copy
    lua_setfield(_state, -1, "__index");

    // expose the table as the global "Host"
    lua_setglobal(_state, name);

    delete luaLname;
}
```

Lets say that I want my Lua code to also be able to view keyboard state as well, and would like the Lua code to access it to look like:

```lua
host = Host.new()
pressed = host.Keyboard.getKeyPressed(1)
```

It becomes easy enough to copy the exact same pattern into the Keyboard class to setup the keyboard table, but I can't seem to come up with a good way to add that Keyboard table to my Host table.  Is there a simple way to do so without messing up my pattern?  Is there a better pattern that I should be using?

I've found plenty of resources on how to create various different aspects of C-Lua APIs, but haven't really found much in terms of patterns/best practices to use while doing so. Also, I know there are libraries, such as LuaBind, that can help with this, but prefer to make my own (at least the first time).

Comment: You should probably use something like luabind - it doesn't require anything lua-specific for C++ classes, and you'd probably actually end up with less code. The one unfortunate thing about it though is that it requires boost (and that I can't find a maintained version of it).

Comment: I "should" use one maybe, but as I said above, I'm trying not to.  This is supposed to be a bit of a learning experience if nothing else. I don't intend to reinvent the wheel forever, but at least until I know how it works. :)

Comment: well, you don't actually have to use third party libraries if you don't want to, but you could at least look at their approach. If you have a decent subset of C++11 features available, you can write something similar (in a basic way, they do seem to do some more complicated things that I didn't really understand) on your own with relatively little effort, which seems more manageable than what you're doing right now to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to take a more OO/Inheritance approach to this problem, and plan on taking a look at how the MOAI SDK implements their Lua API, which looks promising so far.